# Windows Server 2008 R2 Certification Authority into 2003 Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, certificate-authority

Is it supported to install a Certification Authority service on a Windows Server 2008 R2 joined on a 2003 native functional level domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.

However, to get the full functionality of the newer CA (particularly version 3 templates) you'll need to run the 2008 schema upgrades (I don't believe the R2 schema changes impact certificates at all) - which does not require a functional level change or even any newer domain controllers.